# Having trouble printing the final list when appending to a list

Tags: python-3.x

```
def eratos(n): 
    numbers = []
    prime = [True for i in range(n+1)]
    p=2
    while(p <= n):
        if (prime[p] == True):
            for i in range(p * 2, n+1, p):
                prime[i] = False                                
        p+=1
    lis =[]

    # Print all prime numbers
    for p in range(2, n):
        if prime[p]:
            numbers.append(p)
            print(numbers)


    if __name__:
        n = 12
        eratos(n)
```

This will print
    whereas I'd only like the last list [2,3,5,7,11]. 
I understand the for loop I have will check if there is a prime number in my set range then add it into my list then repeat and check for the next number. If possible I'd like for it to check all numbers in the range and then append all of them at the same time, or append one at a time but only return the final list.

Comment: `if __name__:` is rendundant as `__name__` is always going to be a true value. Did you mean `if __name__ == '__main__':` perhaps? Is that indented correctly?

Comment: You need to fix your indentation overall. `print(numbers)` is currently **in the loop**, so will fire each and every time you append. Unindenting would help there.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the **`print`** statement is **in the `for` loop**. Simply move it outside:

```
for p in range(2, n):
    if prime[p]:
        numbers.append(p)
print(numbers) # outside for loop
```

Now the `numbers` list will be printed **after the `for` loop is done**. A final remark: why do you construct `lis`? You never seem to use it.

You can also improve the readability (and a bit of efficiency) with:

```
def eratos(n): 
    prime = [True] * (n+1)
    for p in range(2,n+1):
        if prime[p]:
            for i in range(2*p,n+1,p):
                prime[i] = False

    # Print all prime numbers
    numbers = [p for for p in range(2,n) if prime[p]]
    print(numbers)
```